# git list all branches that's older than remote

Tags: git

When I did

> git fetch

It would compare my local commit history and list the difference between the local and remote on all branches. I wonder if there is a way to display the difference between all my local branches and remote branches?

Comment: I just found out "git branch -vv" maybe what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably easily loop through the output of `git branch`, and for each local branch do `git rev-list --count --left-right origin/$branch..$branch` which would give you counts of which origin branch has ahead/behind which local branch.